# Is there a way to retrieve all stories for any epic that contains a string in jira's jql?

Tags: jira, jql, jira-agile

I have a problem in which I need to generate a dashboard for a large feature which comprises multiple epics.  I would like to be able to search for all of the stories, maybe even technical tasks as well, under any epics which contain the feature name and return this in a search.  Is there a way to do this with Jira's JQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot reference fields as values or functions in JQL.

If you do something like `description ~ summary`, it will either throw an error, or automagically quote it as `description ~ "summary"` and search for the string literal "summary".